# How does sh -e interact with &?

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, exit

I'm using `sh` (`dash`) on Ubuntu (lucid) and the manpage has this to say about `-e`:

```
           -e errexit       If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails.
                            The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly tested
                            if the command is used to control an if, elif, while, or until; or
                            if the command is the left hand operand of an “&&” or “||” opera‐
                            tor.
```

What happens when a background command fails? And does `bash` behave differently in this respect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple to test this. With `-e`:

```
% bash -e -c 'false & echo waiting; if wait $!; then echo success; else echo failure; fi'
waiting
failure
```

So if a backgrounded command fails, the shell will not exit automatically (`-e` is not enough).

If you `wait` outside an explicit test, `wait` will return the return code of the failed backgrounded process. In this case, if `-e` is specified, the shell will exit:

```
% bash -e -c 'false & echo waiting; wait $!; echo returned'   
waiting
```

Same results with `bash` or `sh` or `zsh`.

Comment: `wait` returns the status of the process it waited for. If the subshell fails, the wait fails, too, and makes the whole shell fail.

Comment: @choroba: wow, indeed :-)

Comment: Now, I hope the answer is correct. Thanks choroba.